# Why do i need the gil for PyMem_Malloc()?

Tags: python, python-c-api

As per [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4823854/1658908), `PyMem_Malloc()` requires the GIL; however, if the function is nothing more than an alias for `malloc()`, who cares?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it is sometimes more than simply an alias for `malloc()`.  Sometimes it is an alias for `_PyMem_DebugMalloc()` and there is some global accounting there to keep track of unique memory objects.  There's no real point in releasing the GIL just for a `PyMem_Malloc()` call, so you're probably doing something more complicated in C.  If that's the case, you can simply call `malloc()` and not get any of the debugging stuff.

Comment: As of Python 3.4, there's also `PyMem_RawMalloc()` which doesn't require the GIL to be held (see [PEP 445](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0445/)).