# What parts of a Numpy-heavy function can I accelerate with Cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

<sup>**Introductory notes:** trying to accelerate Python+Numpy code with Cython is a common problem and this question is an attempt to create a canonical question about what types of operation you can accelerate effectively. Although I try to illustrate with a specific example, it is meant as an illustration - please don't focus too much on the fairly meaningless example.</sup>

<sup>Also, I've contributed enough to Cython that I should declare an affiliation (given that I'm bringing the topic up)</sup>

---

**Actual question**

Suppose I have a function that tries to do numeric calculations on Numpy arrays. It uses fairly typical operations:

- a loop over array elements that can't easily be vectorized
- calls to Numpy/Scipy functions (in this case `np.sin`).
- Mathematical operations on the whole array (`a-b`)

```py
import numpy as np

def some_func(a, b):
    """
    a and b are 1D arrays

    This is intended to be illustrative! Please don't focus on what it
    actually does!
    """
    transformed_a = np.zeros_like(a)
    last = 0
    for n in range(1, a.shape[0]):
        an = a[n]
        if an > 0:
            delta = an - a[n-1]
            transformed_a[n] = delta*last
        else:
            last = np.sin(an)
    return transformed_a * b

a = np.random.randn(100)
b = np.linspace(0, 100, a.shape[0])

print(some_func(a, b))
```

Can I speed this up with Cython, and which parts would I expect to be able to speed up?

Comment: Great - it is clear for quite some time that we need such a Q&A!

Comment: @ead Thanks - it's been clear for me too! Feel free to add an answer (or edit mine) if there's anything important you think I've missed!

Answer (score 10):

## Indexing individual array elements

This the main type of code where Cython can *really* help you. Indexing an individual element (e.g. `an = a[n]`) can be a fairly slow operation in Python. Partly because Python is not a hugely quick language and so running Python code lots of times within a loop can be slow, and partly because the array is stored as a tightly-packed array of C floats, but the indexing operation needs to return a Python object. Therefore, indexing a Numpy array requires new Python objects to be allocated.

In Cython you can declare the arrays as [typed memoryviews](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html), or as [`np.ndarray`](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html). (Typed memoryviews are the more modern approach and you should usually prefer them). Doing so allows you to directly access the tightly-packed C array directly and retrieve the C value, without creating a Python object.

The directives `cython.boundscheck` and `cython.wraparound` can be very worthwhile for further speed-ups to the index (but remember they do remove useful features, so *think* before using them).

### vs vectorization

A lot of the time a loop over a Numpy array can be written as a vectorized operation - something that acts on the whole array at once. It is usually a good idea to write Python+Numpy code like this. If you have multiple chained vectorized operations, it is *sometimes* worthwhile to write it explicitly as a Cython loop to avoid allocating intermediate arrays.

Alternatively the little-known [Pythran backend](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/numpy_pythran.html) for Cython convert a set of vectorized Numpy operations to optimized C++ code.

## Indexing array slices

Isn't a problem in Cython, but typically isn't something that will get you significant speed-ups alone.

## Calling Numpy functions

e.g. `last = np.sin(an)`

These require a Python call, so Cython typically *cannot* accelerate these - it has no visibility into the contents of the Numpy function.

*However*, here the operation is on a single value, and not on a Numpy array. In this case we can use `sin` from the C standard library, which will be significantly quicker than a Python function call. You'd do `from libc.math cimport sin` and call `sin` rather than `np.sin`.

Numba is an alternative Python accelerator that has better visibility into Numpy functions can can often optimize without changes.

## Array allocations

e.g. `transformed_a = np.zeros_like(a)`.

This is just a Numpy function call and thus Cython has no ability to speed it up. If it's just an intermediate value and not returned to Python then you might consider a fixed-size C array on the stack

```
cdef double transformed_a[10]  # note - you must know the size at compile-time
```

or by allocating them with the C `malloc` function (remember to `free` it). Or by using Cython's `cython.view.array` (which is still a Python object, but can be a little quicker).

## Whole-array arithmetic

e.g. `transformed_a * b`, which multiplies `transformed_a` and `b` element by element.

Cython doesn't help you here - it's just a disguised function call (although Pythran+Cython may have some benefits). For large arrays this kind of operation is pretty efficient in Numpy so don't overthink it.

Note that whole-array operations aren't defined for Cython typed memoryviews, so you need to do `np.asarray(memview)` to get them back to Numpy arrays. This typically doesn't need a copy and is quick.

For some operations like this, you can use `BLAS` and `LAPACK` functions (which are fast C implementations of array and matrix operations). Scipy provies a Cython interface for them (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.cython_blas.html) to use. They're a little more complex to use that the natural Python code.

## The illustrative example

Just for completeness, I'd write it something like:

```
import numpy as np
from libc.math cimport sin
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def some_func(double[::1] a, b):
    cdef double[::1] transformed_a = np.zeros_like(a)
    cdef double last = 0
    cdef double an, delta
    cdef Py_ssize_t n
    for n in range(1, a.shape[0]):
        an = a[n]
        if an > 0:
            delta = an - a[n-1]
            transformed_a[n] = delta*last
        else:
            last = sin(an)
    return np.asarray(transformed_a) * b
```

which is a little over 10x faster.

`cython -a` is helpful here - it produces an annotated HTML file that shows which lines contain a lot of interaction with Python.

Comment: Great self-anwser! Note that Cython can also help programmers to write parallel Numpy codes. This is an important point as modern desktop processors have about 4-8 cores and computing server ones have typically 16-32 cores. Not to mention the number of core is expected to grow in the future.

Comment: Thanks. I left out parallel code for brevity, but I agree that it can sometimes be very useful

Comment: In addition to prange, I'd suggest to mention multiple loops as a smoking gun for "worth writing as a numpy vectorized expression; failing that, use cython ". This is likely a subset of   the indexing single elements section.

Comment: This is great! One question I have is regarding the difference between using `malloc` and `PyMem_Malloc`. Also if there are general guidelines for using these with, e.g. `try` and `finally` (supposing all dynamic arrays created inside the cython function are deleted before returning). Another thing is that you used `int` for `n`, but why/when is it better to use `long` or, better yet, `Py_ssize_t` instead. This last issue was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20987501/13132315).

Comment: @Breno `Py_ssize_t` would definitely be better than int. I'll update that. I don't have a strong view on `malloc` Vs `PyMem_Malloc` - [as far as I can see they're usually the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823054/is-there-any-reason-to-use-malloc-over-pymem-malloc) but just make sure that the `free` matches. `try/finally` is a very good idea for making sure memory is freed if the lifetime is in a single function. Otherwise you usually want to have a Python object free the memory in a destructor.